# How can I override Pseudo Classes in CSS3

Tags: css

I defined the pseudo class `red:before` and `red:after`, which contain a border-color hexcode. Now I need to switch the color from red to blue using another CSS class named `blue`.

Here is my Html:

```
<div class="red blue">Text</div>
```

And this is my CSS:

```
.red:before, .red:after {
border-color: red;
}
```

How can I set the CSS for `.blue` to make the border-color blue?

Comment: If the switch is dynamic I think it would make more sense to remove the `red` class when adding `blue` class. If it is static, then you should not even put the `red` class in there. Increased specificity will help but you needn't really be having two conflicting classes. Ofcourse this comment is based on the assumption that they have no other properties.

Comment: These are not pseudo-classes, they are pseudo-elements. It is considered correct to write them with double colons `::`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more specific rule should help:

```
div.blue:before, div.blue:after {
  border-color: blue;
}
```

Reference: [MDN - Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Comment: ...or add `!important` to override css rule

Comment: or add the overiding rule after the "default" rule [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/v0dLbaw8/)

Comment: It's better to use **!important** only as last resort.

Comment: @web-tiki indeed but css order is not always known.

Comment: This is not a very good answer. It's not that great to try to manage the cascade by tweaking selectors for specific specificity behaviors. You may be tweaking them for the rest of your life. What if you now want another class `green` that should take precedence? Then would you recommend using `div.green.green`? As another responder said correctly, the proper way to override something is to put it later.

Comment: @torazaburo I completely disagree. Doing this you have to remember always the order of rules and by my working experience that is not possible.

Comment: The order of rules is a fundamental design principle of CSS and a key driver for how the cascade is applied. It is a foundational notion in CSS that you put more general rules first and the override them later.

Comment: @torazaburo That's true but for an inexperienced user that wants to override a rule this solution is better as doesn't need to know advanced css tactics.

Comment: @emmanuel - The problem is that artificially forcing a higher specificity is a good way to start specificity wars, which the order or rules avoids. We should teach the inexperienced the correct ways from the beginning. Torazaburo has it exactly right.

Comment: @Alohci I agree with your point BUT in case of a a cms with plenty of modules (loading separate css files), is it possible to keep track of css order?

Comment: @emmanual - Well, I don't think teaching specificity is that great for a beginner. Even more experienced people get tripped up. Quick, is `:not(.foo)` more specific than `.foo`, or not? Next, they'll be adding id's to everything just to get really high specificity. If you really want a sledgehammer for newbies then just hold your nose and teach them `!important`.

Answer (score 3):

The proper way to override something in css in general all you have to do is to rewrite it again

```css
.red:before, .red:after {
  content: '';
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border: 2px solid red /*we will override this*/
}
```

```html
<div class="red blue">Text</div>
```

Now we override it

```css
.red:before, .red:after {
  content: '';
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border: 2px solid red /*we will override this*/
}
.blue:before, .blue:after {
  border: 2px solid blue
}
```

```html
<div class="red blue">Text</div>
```

But you can clean this up like this

```css
.red:before, .red:after {
  content: '';
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
}
.red:before, .red:after {
  border: 2px solid red 
}
.blue:before, .blue:after {
  border: 2px solid blue
}
```

```html
<div class="red blue">Text</div>
```

Comment: Liked that. Personally I would also prefer abstracting common props into one class while the border could go into a separate one which can be attached or removed as needed.